# Why is the necessary energy for a photon to lift an electron higher than the band gap energy?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

The band gap energy of silicon is around 1 eV and though the required energy for a photon to lift an electron up into the conduction band is around 3.6 eV.

Why is this?

[Is the Energy of an absorbed photon exactly the energy of the band gap?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192430/is-the-energy-of-an-absorbed-photon-exactly-the-energy-of-the-band-gap) is quite similar but - whyever - they do not answer it respectively do not use any material.

Comment: Huh. 1064nm Nd:YAG gets absorbed just fine in silicon, and it isn’t anywhere near 3.6eV. Something is wrong with your sources.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Energy_required_to_create_electron_hole_pair_in_Si_is_36eV_where_as_it_has_a_band_gap_of_11eV_why_there_is_a_difference_between_these_two_values

Comment: The problem is I don't see an explanation there - or do not understand it..

Comment: As I noted, silicon absorbs light just fine well below 3.6eV, starting in the near infrared. And, no, I’m not going to go read some random article on reaearchgate that tries to tell me otherwise.

Comment: According to http://www.desy.de/~niebuhr/Vorlesung/Detektor/Vorlesung_4.pdf the band gap energy is 1.12 eV and the ionization energy is 3.6 eV.Thus, what I conclude is, normally, in semiconductors there are no free electrons in the valence band and thus you will need >3.6 eV to lift an electron up into the conduction band.
Thanks.

Comment: here it is explicit: http://www.desy.de/~schleper/lehre/Det_Dat/SS_2018/03-lecture_Silicon.1-23.pdf 
Just in case you consider it as "random": Desy is an particle accelerator and these are lecture notes.

Comment: Anyhow, now I think the required energy must be around 5 eV = ionization energy + band gap energy...

Comment: There are lots of electrons in the valence band (it is almost all electrons). The number in the conduction band is set by doping levels and temperature, but there are never ‘no’ electrons in the conduction band.

Comment: "free" electrons I wrote

Comment: Look, if your Si CMOS camera in your phone only responded to light above 3.6eV your pictures would look very different.

Comment: and why do they mention these 3.6 eV?

Comment: Maybe 3.6 eV is the direct band gap of Si. Below that is indirect, requiring, e.g., a phonon to complete the absorption process. 1.1 eV is the *indirect* band gap of Si.

Comment: Page 8,10 and 11 in that PDF show the Si gap as 1.1eV which is roughly 1micron IR light (and above, including visible)

Comment: Yes, true. So for the direct band gap I need energy of 3.6 eV which is not visible light. The indirect band gap is 1.12 eV but why can visible light bridge this gap? As far as I understood you need more energy than the band gap energy for indirect band gap transitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silicon has an *indirect* band gap. This means that although there is a conduction-band state which is only 1eV above the top of the conduction band it occurs at a different Bloch momentum ${\bf k}$. The nearest state with the samae ${\bf k}$ value is 3.6eV above the top of the valance band. Photons have a wavelength $\approx 600\mu$ that it is much larger than the inter-atom spacing and so their crystal momentum ${\bf k}$ is much smaller than the size of the Brillouin zone. Their momentum  is therefore effectively zero as far as band theory is concerned. Therefore, for single-photon absorbtion with none of the energy going into phonons (to make up the momentum change) you need 3.6 eV photons.

LED's and other devices that play well  with light are made of III-V or (or even II-VI) materials such as Gallium Arsenide or Indium Arsenide that have *direct* band gaps, meansing that the lowest energy conduction-band state has the same ${\bf k}$ as topmost valence band state.

There is some discussion of this in he Wikipedia page on Direct and indirect band gaps

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing this! My solid physics lecture is a while ago, can you please describe shortly the bloch momentum k and why it is different in silicon?

Comment: btw, another question: The ionization needs 3.6 eV, does that mean the eh-pair is created such that the electron is in the conduction band? Or do I still need 1.12 eV to lift the electron up into the conduction band?

Comment: I just found that here in https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s8664_series_kapd1012e.pdf the photodiode, made of silicon, has its highest quantum efficiency in the visible range of light.
?